# Oracle form builder 10g

Tags: oracle10g

While create a form in oracle form builder, In data block wizard am getting an error when giving my user,password,database and click "Ok".

> Error is : ORQ-12154:TNS: could not resolve the connect identifier
>   specified.

How to solve this error. plz anyone can help me??

Answer (score 0):

you should configure TNSNAMES.ora file -it is in form builder folder;

> Add the following entry in your TNSNAMES.ORA file and change the values shown in brackets to suit your environment:

```
<addressname> =
 (DESCRIPTION =
   (ADDRESS_LIST =
     (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(Host = <hostname>)(Port = <port>))
   )
 (CONNECT_DATA =
   (SERVICE_NAME = <service_name>)
 )
)
```

Here is a completed example:

```
ORA11 =
 (DESCRIPTION = 
   (ADDRESS_LIST =
     (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.1.0)(PORT = 1521))
   )
 (CONNECT_DATA =
   (SERVICE_NAME = ORA12)
 )
)
```

READ THIS ARTICLE http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Tnsnames.ora

Comment: You should copy the most important part from that article before linking it as the link might go offline in future - providing no value. Also please fix the link.

Comment: A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please [add context around the link](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. Take into account that being *barely more than a link to an external site* is [a possible reason for your answer to be deleted](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).